# sql.js GUI example - Force a specific database instead of select one

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I'm trying to use [SQL.JS](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/) in order to build a simple local SQLite database browser without any server interaction.

I'm using the [GUI example page](http://kripken.github.io/sql.js/GUI/) to test.

The HTML GUI example page uses `<input type='file' id='dbfile'>`
in order to allow the user to select the database file, then the HTML page calls GUI.JS like this:

```js
var dbFileElm = document.getElementById('dbfile');

// Load a db from a file
dbFileElm.onchange = function() {
    var f = dbFileElm.files[0];
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = function() {
        worker.onmessage = function () {
            toc("Loading database from file");
            // Show the schema of the loaded database
            editor.setValue("SELECT `name`, `sql`\n  FROM `sqlite_master`\n  WHERE type='table';");
            execEditorContents();
        };
        tic();
        try {
            worker.postMessage({action:'open',buffer:r.result}, [r.result]);
        }
        catch(exception) {
            worker.postMessage({action:'open',buffer:r.result});
        }
    }
    r.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}
```

And it's working fine.

Now I would like to force a specific database name and location. I try to use :
`<input type='text' value='<MY_DB_FILE>' id='dbfile'>` (where MY_DB_FILE is the name of my DB file located in the same folder as the HTML page). I also change

`dbFileElm.onchange = function()` into `dbFileElm.onload = function()`

But nothing works and the ID dbfile doesn't seem to contain any usable data and the function is not called.

Comment: What do you mean by "Now I would like to force a specific database name and location."

Comment: in the line "<input type='text' value='<MY_DB_FILE>' id='dbfile'>" I cannot manage to find a way to specify the path and/or the DB file name I want to use. But since this question, I abandon the idea and build a C# browser that work well but exit cross plaform support.